# how to read excel in jsp

Tags: html, apache, jsp

How to get the file path of excel selected in browse button to filepath string variable. I want to read that excel as shown below. Am i doing it right. Or is there anything i have to change in this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form class="form-group" method="post">

    <label class="control-label">Select File</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">

    </body>
    </html>

    <%

    String filename = "";
    //how to get the full filepath here from browse button
    //so that i can read the excel
    if (filename != null && !filename.equals("")) {

             FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(filename);
             XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
             XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
             int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
             for (int r = 1; r < rows; r++) {
                   XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
                      if (row != null) {
                       //reading excel is done
                          }
                }
    } 


    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that...

```
5   import java.io.*;
6   import java.util.*;
7   
8   public class importExcel
9   {
10  
11      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
12      {
13          
14          createWorkbook("excel-poi.xls");
15          
16          readWorkbook("excel-poi.xls");
17          
18      }
19  
20      private static void createWorkbook(String filename) throws Exception
21      {
22          
23          HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
24          
25          HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("mySheet");
26  
27          sheet.setZoom(2, 1);
28          
29          HSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
30          font.setFontHeightInPoints( (short) 18 );
31          font.setFontName("Arial");
32          font.setItalic(true);
33          
34          HSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
35          style.setFont(font);
36          
37          for (int rownum = 0; rownum < 5; rownum++)
38          {
39              HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum);
40              for (short cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < 5; cellIndex++)
41              {
42                  HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellIndex);
43                  cell.setCellStyle(style);
44                  cell.setCellValue(cellIndex + (rownum * 10));
45              }
46          }
47          
48          FileOutputStream fos = null;
49          
50          fos = new FileOutputStream("hello-poi.xls");
51          
52          wb.write(fos);
53          
54          fos.flush();
55          
56          fos.close();
57          
58      }
59  
60      private static void readWorkbook(String filename) throws Exception
61      {
62          
63          InputStream input = new FileInputStream(filename);
64          
65          HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(input);
66          
67          for (int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetIndex++)
68          {
69              HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
70              Iterator rowIter = sheet.rowIterator();
71              while (rowIter.hasNext())
72              {
73                  HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
74                  Iterator cellIter = row.cellIterator();
75                  while (cellIter.hasNext())
76                  {
77                      HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
78                      printCellValue(cell);
79                  }
80              }
81          }
82          
83          input.close();
84      }
85          
86  
87      private static void printCellValue(HSSFCell c)
88      {
89          
90          int cellType = c.getCellType();
91          
92          if (cellType == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN)
93          {
94              System.out.println(c.getBooleanCellValue());
95          }
96          else if (cellType == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
97          {
98              System.out.println(c.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
99          }
100         else if (cellType == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA)
101         {
102             System.out.println(c.getCellFormula());
103         }
104         else if (cellType == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
105         {
106             System.out.println(c.getNumericCellValue());
107         }
108         else if (cellType == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR)
109         {
110             System.out.println(c.getErrorCellValue());
111         }
112     }
113 }
```

I have used Apache POI. If you dont know about it..
Read the article. It is really easy and helpful.
https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/
Notify me , If you have not got still.

Comment: for excel reading part similar code is used. But i'm unable to get the path of the file direcly to the filepath variable. Can we read excel directly from web app if path is available. After reading each cell, i'm storing each cell in mysql db. Do i have to upload the excel first to server and then read from hardcoded path?

Comment: I want to read the excel file from user PC in web app. Is it possible to read cell by cell and insert the cell values to mysql db. Or do i have to upload the file first to server and then read it?(JSP is used to build web app)

Comment: Yes, you have to upload the file first to server. Then you would able to read.[ViRaPa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7912522/virapa)

Comment: Is there any possibility that i can access the file without uploading to server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using below code to upload the file to server. Is it proper?  The path "d:/new" in the code, is it server path or client PC path. Do i have to specify client pc path anywhere. Or it will directly take the path while clicking browse button and select the file?

```
index.html
                    <html>  
                    <body>  
                    <form action="go" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
                    Select File:<input type="file" name="fname"/><br/>  
                    <input type="submit" value="upload"/>  
                    </form>  
                    </body>  
                    </html> 


                UploadServlet.java


                import java.io.*;  
                import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
                import javax.servlet.http.*;  
                import com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest;  

                public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {  

                public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
                    throws ServletException, IOException {  

                response.setContentType("text/html");  
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  

                MultipartRequest m=new MultipartRequest(request,"d:/new");  
                out.print("successfully uploaded");  
                }  
                } 

    web.xml

    <web-app>  

    <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>UploadServlet</servlet-class>  
    </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/go</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  

    </web-app>
```